# How to create time objects in GMT

Tags: ruby

We use the `Time.now` function to fetch the time corresponding to a certain timezone. What would be the simplest way to create time object in GMT and how do I translate this into a certain timezone/locale (e.g. `PST/en_US, JST, ja_JP`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time.now.utc` for a first part and [tzinfo](http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/doc/files/README.html) for a 2nd

Answer (score 2):

`Time.now.gmtime` will give you the gmt.
Use **I18n** to localize it 
eg : `I18n.localize(time, :format => :date_format_MMM_D_YYYY)`

Answer (score 2):

For GMT, use

```
Time.now.utc # it returns UTC time => "2011-12-14 07:05:18 UTC"
```

For local time, you can use `active_support/time`. You require the gem and use the `in_time_zone` method

```
require 'active_support/time'
Time.now.in_time_zone('<time_zone>')
```

eg:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Kolkata') # It returns time in IST => Wed, 14 Dec 2011 12:39:07 IST +05:30
Time.now.in_time_zone('Paris') # It returns French time => Wed, 14 Dec 2011 08:13:40 CET +01:00
```